# Putting two <div> side by side

Tags: css

I want to put two  side by side on another (I have three  )
this is my code:

```
<div class=Mheader >
<div class=theader>
Meine Route !
</div>
<div class=imgcss>
 <img src="Images/Route1.png" width=600 height=100 />
</div>
```

but the image always goes under the text .how can I solve this problem?
my CSS is:

```
.Mheader
{
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS';
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #008800;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
}
.theader
{
    font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Demi';
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: normal;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: left;
    height: 100px;
}
.imgcss
{
    text-align: right;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `float:left;` in `.theader` and  `.imgcss` classes

Answer (score 1):

Give `float` to them . Write like this:

```
.imgcss,
.theader{
 float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just `float: left` both  `.theader` and `.imgcss` element and be sure that parent element is at least `850px` large *(600px+250px)*

```
.imgcss, .theader{
    ...
    float    : left;
}

.Mheader {
    ...
    min-width : 850px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want the green header to span across screen, and that the image/logo should float on right-hand side inside this header. To achieve this:

1. Close the `.Mheader`. with the missing  `</div>`
2. Add `float: left` to the .theaeder. Keep the `width: auto`
3. Add `float: right` to the .imgcss

See a demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/mtbwD/